# PHP unable to open include file

Tags: php, apache, lamp

I have a problem with a PHP script. The following error is being logged whenever the site is accessed:

```
[Fri Sep 26 11:57:56 2014] [error] [client 31.22.44.2] 
PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
 './sites/default/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_markup.inc' 
(include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in 
/var/www/www.xoomtalk.com/htdocs/sites/default/modules/views/includes/handlers.inc
 on line 76
```

I have confirmed that the file referenced is present, and that www-data can access it. Permissions look fine and have not been changed as far as I am aware

What am I missing?

Comment: Make sure that the path is valid.

Comment: Have you tried adding the whole path? i.e. /var/www/www.xoomtalk.com/htdocs/sites/default/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_markup.inc instead of ./sites/default/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_markup.inc

Comment: Maybe better suited at Drupal Answers (http://drupal.stackexchange.com/) as this is a Views problem.

Comment: **How** did you verify the file is present from the given basepath ? Because the PHP error means the relative path is not correct. Verify it by using the absolute path: `/var/www/www.xoomtalk.com/htdocs/sites/default/modules/views/includes/views_handler_field_markup.inc`

Comment: @DanFromGermany I verified it was a valid path using `cat /var/www/www.xoomtalk.com/htdocs/sites/default/modules/views/includes/views_han‌​dler_field_markup.inc` which returned the contents of the file

Comment: @btongeorge That does not verify the relative path is correct. Either use an absolute path or set a basepath then include like `require BASEPATH . '/sites/defaul.....;` (which results in an absolute path), or set the include_path. The answer below explains this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this problem, ended up being nothing to do with permissions or paths, although there was no indication of this in the Apache logs.

The problem was that the server was also running AppArmor which for some reason was blocking the Apache process from accessing the files.

AppArmor was set to complain rather than enforce mode for testing (command is `aa-complain apache2`) this made everything start working.

Thanks to all contributors for their suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

> [Fri Sep 26 11:57:56 2014] [error] [client 31.22.44.2] PHP Fatal
>   error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
>   './sites/default/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_markup.inc'
>   (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in
>   /var/www/www.xoomtalk.com/htdocs/sites/default/modules/views/includes/handlers.inc
>   on line 76

**Add path `/var/www/www.xoomtalk.com/htdocs` into your include_path**

More explains:

your `include_path=.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear` , means php script will find include file in: current_path, /usr/share/php or /usr/share/pear

when you want to require this file 
./sites/default/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_markup.inc

all allowed path are:
(current path)
/var/www/www.xoomtalk.com/htdocs/sites/default/modules/views/includes/./sites/default/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_markup.inc

(/usr/share/php) /usr/share/php/./sites/default/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_markup.inc

(/usr/share/pear)
/usr/share/pear/sites/default/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_markup.inc

In these path ,php can't find the file.

Comment: I have included the www directory in the path but still getting the same error. Does this mean it must be something permission related? The file is definitely there as I can see its contents

Answer (score 1):

in the following file:
/var/www/www.xoomtalk.com/htdocs/sites/default/modules/views/includes/handlers.inc
 on line 76

Change This:

```
'./sites/default/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_markup.inc'
```

to THIS: `'/var/www/www.xoomtalk.com/htdocs/sites/default/modules/views/handlers/views_handler_field_markup.inc'`

This should do the trick.
The problem is, you're using scripts from various directories, but the "root" of the request is the cwd (current working directory) which you can check with: getcwd()
(and you're requesting the include *relative* to the cwd.